# Change sliding text on JQuery range slider tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to change the text when the slider gets moved to the right side from the middle and change to another text when the slider is moved towards the left side from the middle and change into another text when the slider is at the exact middle(starting position)(The pop-up tooltip should be permanent)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input autocomplete="on" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="10" 
           id="agriculture" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
           title="Hey! You should drag me!">
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $("#agriculture").tooltip();
```

Here is my current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iviknesh/H2FZQ/15/) setup.

Please help me to achieve this. If i move the slider, some function must be called and the text should be changed according to the position.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MK55f/

You can set a handler on mouseup and use `val()` to get the current range value and set the `title` attribute with `attr()`

In my fiddle I commented out the `.tooltip()` as I didn't see what the point was and it seemed to override the default tooltip provided by the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the change with "input change" events :

```
        $('#agriculture').on('input change', function () {
```

Then get the value and change the title according to the value with that :

```
        $("#agriculture").tooltip('hide')
                          .attr('data-original-title', 'New Title')
                          .tooltip('fixTitle')
                          .tooltip('show');
```

**The DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/Finrod/H2FZQ/25/